# Java EE / Struts persistent sessions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm doing my first Java EE web application and I'm struggling with sessions.

in my web.xml file I put the following settings:

```xml
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But if I close my browser which is not configured to delete cookies on close,
after reopen the session is over.

How can I have a "persistent" session ?

Comment: Can you try inspecting headers sent and inspect cookies being sent

Answer (score 0):

check if a cookie named Jsessionid is getting created during your first request. And close your browser open it again and check if that cookie is still there and value is same.

I think it will not be, and that is the reason your session expires.

Comment: Yes, each time I get a new value, but I don't know why Expire is set to "Session", seems like the session-timeout value is not used.

Answer (score 0):

When a cookie's expiration is set to "session", it will get deleted by the browser when the user closes the browser. This has nothinng to do with the web.xml `session-timeout` setting, which will force-close the Java EE session server-side if there are no requests by the user in the designated timespan.

Spring has "remember me" functionality:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html

Comment: I'm not able to use Spring, only struts and hibernate, so do I need to write and read/intercept my own cookie ?